# How match elements from two lists in scala?

Tags: list, scala, collections

I have two list as given following-

```
val a = List((HarddiskVolume1,31,1), (C:,46552070,433057), (E:,5435,1728), (_Total,46557536,434786))
val b =  List(C:, E:)
```

I wants output as following:
    o/p
    (C:,46552070,433057), (E:,5435,1728)

How do I get desired output using scala??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val a = List(("HarddiskVolume1",31,1), ("C:",46552070,433057), ("E:",5435,1728), ("_Total",46557536,434786))     

val b =  List("C:", "E:")

a.filter(x => b.contains(x._1))  // if b is large, consider making it a set.
// res0: List[(String, Int, Int)] = List((C:,46552070,433057), (E:,5435,1728))
```

Comment: Hi I had same problem if my list as val a =List(List((HarddiskVolume1,31,1), (C:,46552070,433057), (E:,5435,1728), (_Total,46557536,434786)), List((HarddiskVolume1,31,1), (C:,46552070,433057), (E:,5435,1728), (_Total,46557536,434786))) then how should filter add?

Answer (score 2):

Using `collect` like this,

```
val keys = b.toSet
a collect { case z@(x,_,_) if keys(x) => z }
```

**Update**

Other similar approaches include

```
for ( z <- a if keys(z._1) ) yield z

a collect { case z if keys(z._1) => z }

( a partition ( z =>  keys(z._1) ) )._1
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering @Yogesh in case the data exists as a list within a list:

```
val aa =List(List(("HarddiskVolume1",31,1), ("C:",46552070,433057), ("E:",5435,1728), ("_Total",46557536,434786)),
             List(("HarddiskVolume1",31,1), ("C:",46552070,433057), ("E:",5435,1728), ("_Total",46557536,434786))
            )
val b =  List("C:", "E:")

aa.map(l => l.filter(x => b.exists(_== x._1)))
```

Similar to Shyamendra but using exists operator on a list.